# Creating while loop in Java when making menus

Tags: java, menu, java.util.scanner, do-while

I've been attempting to create a menu using the 'do' feature in Java. I start by providing the user with a range of options, then I request the user to enter their option through the keyboard and in turn, creating the string variable 'selection'. However when I reference the 'selection' variable in my loop expression, the error indication appears with "selection cannot be resolved to a variable". Why is that so and how can I correct this?

Please refer to the code below.

```
do{
       //output presenting the user with options
        System.out.print("A simple Menu\n");
        System.out.print("Y - Yolk\n");
        System.out.print("N - Naan\n");
        System.out.print("X - Exit\n\n");

        //request user input using the import.util.*; feature
        System.out.print("Enter your selection: ");
        String selection=keyboard.nextLine();
        // So here the 'selection' string is made

       }
       //Now here, whatever the user has selected as an option will be 
       // passed through and more options will appear.
       while(selection!="X");

       //however I get prompted with the red squiggly line underneath the 
       //'selection' variable that seems to not recognize 'selection' as a string
```

Comment: To fix the other problem, simply define `selection` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `selection` variable is out of the scope (or you can think as already destroyed) when the loop trying to check it again. so define it outside the loop.

```
String selection ="";
        do{
           //output presenting the user with options
            System.out.print("A simple Menu\n");
            System.out.print("Y - Yolk\n");
            System.out.print("N - Naan\n");
            System.out.print("X - Exit\n\n");

            //request user input using the import.util.*; feature
            System.out.print("Enter your selection: ");
            selection=keyboard.nextLine();
            // So here the 'selection' string is made

           }
           //Now here, whatever the user has selected as an option will be 
           // passed through and more options will appear.
           while(!selection.equals("X"));
```

**Edit**

I totally agree with @ Tim Biegeleisen. But His error message is not about the String comparison with logical operator. anyway I edited my answer. Thank you very much for pointing out about it.

Comment: Logically compare strings using `String#equals()` _not_ `!=`.

Comment: Thank you Shanil. by defining my variable 'selection' outside the do-while loop I now have been able to proceed with the program. I've also implemented '!selection.equals("X")' within the while expression. Many Thanks Tim!